# How to Remove texts between two Specific words of a string by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I remove texts between two specific words of a string with JavaScript?

For example: `"Steven Peter Title: Random Text Company: Random Text"`
I want to remove texts from `"Title:"` to `"Company: "`

Isn't there any simple way to remove texts from one word to another in JavaScript?

Comment: What have u tried for it..

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research? As it is, this question is too broad, and will probably be closed as such. Try to search around a bit for possible solutions, try coding something, and come back for help (With a example of what you tried), if you can't get it to work. SO is not a site where you can just post a requirement and expect code in return.

Comment: I searched here and google b4 asking but didn't find anything for similar situation ... Also I tried str.replace but didn't know how to remove the random text between those 2 words... BTW what did u find so broad here??!! HUH??!! It was a simple question about specific situation!!

Answer (score 1):

The String.replace method with a regular expression should do exactly what you are looking for. See: http://jsfiddle.net/je380fcg/

```
var txt = "Steven Peter Title: Random Text Company: Random Text";
document.getElementById("orig").innerHTML = txt;

var newTxt = txt.replace(/Title:.*Company:/, "");
document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = newTxt;
```