# In Javascript, I need a RegEx to remove text in a string between 2 texts (range) with multiple apperance

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Let's say I have this string:

```
var str = 'abc abcd --from-- xyz xyzz --to-- abc abcdd --from-- xsfkj --to-- abc';
```

My method should remove all the text between `--from--` and `--to--`.
I think the best way is to do it with RegEx, I just don't know how...

I looked into [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608199/how-to-remove-texts-between-two-specific-words-of-a-string-by-javascript) but I got this string as a result:

```
console.log(str.replace(/--from--.*--to--/, "")); // result:"abc abcd  abc", not good.
```

In addition, is it possible to set a parameter instead of hard coded text in the range borders?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need global flag with lazy quantifier:

```
console.log(str.replace(/--from--.*?--to--/g, ""));
//=> abc abcd  abc abcdd  abc
```

**Update:**

You can use variables in regex like this:

```
var from = '--from--'; 
var to = '--to--';
var re = new RegExp(from + '.*?' + to, "g");

console.log(str.replace(re, ""));
```

Comment: Thanks :) What about setting a parameter instead of hard coded string? i mean var from = '--from--'; => setting that.

Comment: I have just discovered the [\s\S] instead of '.' (dot) for multi-line. So for this solution to work for multi-line text, there's a need to replace the dot with [\s\S] as follows: var re = new RegExp(from + '[\\s\\S]*?' + to, "g");

Comment: Yes that's the tick used in js regex to match any character across multilines.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a non greedy and put the replace part in a capture group or use look around :

```
str.replace(/--from--(.*?)--to--/g, "")
```

And if you want to replace `--from--` and `--to--` you don't need capture group anymore.

```
str.replace(/--from--.*?--to--/g, "")
```

Comment: You're missing the `g` flag.